# Вукомерс вывод товаров из определённой категории

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Понадобилось вывести товары из определённой категории таблицей с доп полмя.
Заколхозил вот так

```
add_shortcode( 'iframe', 'Generate_iframe' );

function Generate_iframe( $atts ) {
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
  'cat_id' => 21,
  'post_type' => 'product', 
  'posts_per_page' => 40,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
  'order' => 'ASC',
  )); 
echo "
<table class=\"tabletov\">
    <tr class=\"theadtov\">
        <td>
            SKU
        </td>
        <td>
            Зона покрытия
        </td>
        <td>
            Тип термостата
        </td>
        <td>
            Напряжение коврика  
        </td>
        <td>
            Ширина коврика  
        </td>
        <td>
            Длина коврика   
        </td>
        <td>
            Текущие амперы  
        </td>
        <td>
            Пиковая мощность    
        </td>
        <td>
            Цена за единицу 
        </td>
        <td>
            
        </td>
    </tr>
";
while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class=\"sku-text\" align=\"center\">";
            echo "<a href=\"";
            echo the_permalink();
            echo "\">";
            echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="sku"]' );
            echo "</a>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="зона_покрытия"]' );
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="тип_термостата"]' );
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="напряжение_коврика"]' );
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="ширина_коврика"]' );
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="длина_коврика"]' );
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="текущие_амперы"]' );
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="пиковая_мощность"]' );
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo  woocommerce_template_loop_price();
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 endwhile;
 wp_reset_postdata();
echo "</table>";
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но при добавлении ещё одной таблицы но с другой подкатегорией выводит вообще все товары. в частности данная проблема вообще не была видна пока не понадобилась вторая таблица.

Comment: wp_reset_postdata() профукал

Comment: а где примерно профукал, а то голова уже идёт кругом и туго очень соображаю. Вставил после завершения цикла но история всё та же.

Comment: Кури WP_Query. И следи за вложенностью тегов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После endwhile нужно добавить wp_reset_postdata().
Вам нужно изменить аргументы для выборки товаров по категории

```
 $args = [
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 40,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 21,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ],
    ],
];
$loop = new WP_Query($args );
```

Comment: в том то и дело что добавил, но песня всё та же.

Comment: как вы передаёте id нужной категории в шорткод? Обновите код в вопросе

Comment: да я изначально объявляю вызов функции по шорткоду, ид категории в функции указываю cat_id в массиве loop

Comment: ну как минимум wp_query не принимает параметр cat_id, для wp_query есть параметр  cat в который указывается id рубрики но у вас немного другой случай

Comment: @LinuX_UseR вы не правильно передаете аргументы в wp_query, я обновил ответ